# How to force a ListView not to expand more than other widgets in a row (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, listview, row, height

I'm struggling with this and can't describe it as well as I should on search engine, so here's my problem: I have a Row containing two Expanded with `flex: 5` aiming to have two width-equal cells; inside the first cell, I have a Column (containing a Table and a Button); inside the second cell I have a Column (containing a ListView and a Button); I'd like to force the ListView to become scrollable once its content gets higher than first cell's intrinsic height, so second cell's height never gets higher than first cell's height.

```
Row(
   children: [
      Expanded(
         flex: 5,
         child: Column(
            children: [
               DataTable(),
               ElevatedButton()
            ]
         ), // Column
      ), // Expanded
      Expanded(
         flex: 5,
         child: Column(
            children: [
               ListView(),
               ElevatedButton()
            ]
         ), // Column
      ) // Expanded
   ]
) // Row
```

I lost myself trying stuff with `shrinkWrap: true` on the ListView, `IntrinsicHeight()` around the Row, etc.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

Solution I found is going the hard way by listening to first cell's size changes and to set its height as second cell's height (thanks to [this Medium link](https://medium.com/flutterworld/flutter-how-to-get-the-height-of-the-widget-be4892abb1a2)). Even tho I'd rather go for a cleaner way, it seems to work like it should.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
Row(
   children: [
      Expanded(
         flex: 5,
         child: WidgetSize(
            onChange: (size) {
               if (size != null)
                  setState(() => heightOfTable = (size as Size).height);
            },
            child: Column(
               children: [
                  DataTable(),
                  ElevatedButton()
               ]
            ), // Column
         ), // WidgetSize
      ), // Expanded
      Expanded(
         flex: 5,
         child: Container(
            height: heightOfTable,
            child: Column(
               children: [
                  ListView(),
                  ElevatedButton()
               ]
            ), // Column
         ), // Container
      ) // Expanded
   ]
) // Row
```

If you've got a better idea, please let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try wrapping the `ListView` inside a `Container` and give a suitable `height` and `width.

```
Row(
   children: [
      Expanded(
         flex: 5,
         child: Column(
            children: [
               DataTable(),
               ElevatedButton()
            ]
         ), // Column
      ), // Expanded
      Expanded(
         flex: 5,
         child: Column(
            children: [
               Container(
           height:,
           width:,
          child: ListView()),
               ElevatedButton()
            ]
         ), // Column
      ) // Expanded
   ]
) // Row
```

Comment: I'd like not to use hardcoded values and let Table's height (defined by its content) to define ListView's height.